# How can I get total posts in as few queries as possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using OpenGraph, I need to get the user IDs of people who have posted on my profile the most, and I have posted to the most (or tagged in posts).

Using FQL I could have just added an order by clause.  As FQL is now deprecated, I need to use OpenGraph instead, but there doesn't seem an easy way to do this.

The only way that seems possible is to get several pages of posts by grabbing `/me/feed`, and then querying each ID individually to get more info on it.  This could easily result in hundreds, if not thousands of queries, for something pretty simple.

So my question:  Is it possible to order an OpenGraph query by the number of posts made by a certain person to and from my profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ordering by the number of posts made to your feed is not possible. You'll have to get all posts and calculate the numbers yourself, unfortunately.